# How can I stop my application from force closing?

Tags: java, android

I am making a example app for GPS positioning on my Evo 4G. This is to eventually be integrated into a app for time card use. But, it force closes. I don't have any ideas why... Any help?

```
package com.Rick.GPS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener {

/* this class implements LocationListener, which listens for both
 * changes in the location of the device and changes in the status
 * of the GPS system.
 * */

static final String tag = "Main"; // for Log

TextView txtInfo;
LocationManager lm;
StringBuilder sb;
int noOfFixes = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* get TextView to display the GPS data */
    txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);

    /* the location manager is the most vital part it allows access
     * to location and GPS status services */
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}


protected void onResume() {
    /*
     * onResume is is always called after onStart, even if the app hasn't been
     * paused
     *
     * add location listener and request updates every 1000ms or 10m
     */
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);
    super.onResume();
}


protected void onPause() {
    /* GPS, as it turns out, consumes battery like crazy */
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.v(tag, "Location Changed");

    sb = new StringBuilder(512);

    noOfFixes++;

    /* display some of the data in the TextView */

    sb.append("No. of Fixes: ");
    sb.append(noOfFixes);
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Londitude: ");
    sb.append(location.getLongitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Latitude: ");
    sb.append(location.getLatitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Altitiude: ");
    sb.append(location.getAltitude());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Accuracy: ");
    sb.append(location.getAccuracy());
    sb.append('\n');

    sb.append("Timestamp: ");
    sb.append(location.getTime());
    sb.append('\n');

    txtInfo.setText(sb.toString());
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    /* this is called if/when the GPS is disabled in settings */
    Log.v(tag, "Disabled");

    /* bring up the GPS settings */
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.v(tag, "Enabled");
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    /* This is called when the GPS status alters */
    switch (status) {
    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Out of Service");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Out of Service",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
        Log.v(tag, "Status Changed: Available");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Status Changed: Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}


protected void onStop() {
    /* may as well just finish since saving the state is not important for this toy app */
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Here is the layout file...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

And here is the manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Rick.GPS"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GPSActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help you can give me...

Comment: Look in the log file for an exception. That should tell you where the problem lies. (To see the LogCat in Eclipse, open the LogCat view (Window > Show View > Other..., then select LogCat under Android).

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes I could spot:

1. You need the call to `setContentView(R.layout.main);`, don't comment it. otherwise, you get a NullPointerException in the next line.
2. In the XML you define `Text1` as `EditText`, but than in your class you try to cast it to `TextView` and you get class cast exception. Change it either in the XML or in the java file. According to your comment in the code, you should change it in the XML.

Comment: Thanks, I changed both... still force closes                                                                 Log cat states: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main"

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void onPause() {     /* GPS, as it turns out, consumes battery like crazy */     lm.removeUpdates(this);     super.onPause(); }
```

ALSO THE setContentView code is commented...

Answer (score 0):

Does onLocationChange have access to the textField? Anyway, I think a better way to design this application would be to do the location listening in a separate thead, and for example use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update the UI thread. This approach also removes the risk that a location fix might block the UI-thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling super.onResume in the body of your onPause method.